# WSO2 IS 5.3 RC1 as API Keymanager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I recently downloaded the 5.3 RC1 distribution of IS and now I want to set it up to be a key manager for WSO2 API Manager 1.10. I checked the Wilkes p2 repo for a compatible version of the key manager to be installed as a feature, but I can't find any. Neither of versions 5.0.3 and 6.0.4 are installable with the 5.3 RC1 version of WSO2 IS. Is there any way I can proceed from this point, or do I have to wait for the GA release and hope for the compatible key management feature to appear in the p2 repo?

Furthermore, will it even be possible to use the combination of APIM 1.10 and IS 5.3, or will 5.3 require an update of APIM or that IS 5.3 be treated as a 3rd party key manager?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we managed to sort this out. To start with, WSO2 IS 5.3 was released Jan 11, 2017, but it took a few weeks after APIM 2.1.0 was relased that the required feature (Key Manager feature v 6.1.66) appeared in the p2 repository. Then we used the instructions in the documentation for API Manager to configure [Identity Server as key manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager).
But that only did part of the work since there are incompatibility issues at database and service levels, so we had to fix those. A description of what we did to get APIM 1.10.0 to work with IS 5.3 can be found at [Github](https://github.com/vasttrafik/wso2-knowledge-base).